# Ajax Contact form going to spam in Gmail

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "example@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

    //proceed with PHP email.

    $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out here? I assume its a decent form from what I have seen online, with headers etc. No idea why this would be going to gmail spam, tried to find solution and made changes but no luck.

Comment: How the fridge are we suppose to make anything out of your code? At least show some effort in asking a proper question.

Comment: Sorry I clicked post before I realised :(

Answer (score 1):

There are no obvious errors in your code..  GMail (and other mailers) need far more information to be included in the headers than this in order to raise the spam score above the spam threshold.

Consider using a more refined mailer stystem, something like PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ or other simillar classes in order to generate your email.  These will generate the required headers and format the email enough to prevent most (if not all) mail clients marking the email as spam.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I will be switching to phpmailer :)

Comment: Awesome.  PHPMailer is fab!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you used library for sending mail, if it displaying in spam then always check your header in your mail data.

Please check your header information I'm definitely sure you miss something.

For any simple mail, there require some minimum header information.

Like,

```
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: MyCompany <abc@mycompany.com>' . "\r\n";
```

You can add more as per your required. Good Luck ['}

Comment: If you got your answer then accept and mark as answer so our friends those who are facing same problem get idea directly and get easily.... 

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check your mail headers (in Gmail itself) to see why the SPAM score is that high.
Note that a lot of spamfilters check if there is only HTML in the email or only images, which can be the cause of a high SPAM score.

I don't know much about the Gmail spamfilters but I do know that our spamfilters check on stuff like that.